# On `Promise` and `then()` execution order

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Let's say I have a function like this

```js
const fn = () => {
    return work()
    .then((finalResult) => {     // then 1
        finish(finalResult);
    });
};


const work = () => {
    return Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(() => {                // then 2
        return process1();
    }).then((result) => {        // then 3
        return process2(result);
    });
};
```

My question is: can I rely on the fact that `finish` will be called AFTER `process1` and `process2`. Specifically, is `then 1` attached to the promise returned by `Promise.resolve(1)` or is it attached to the promise returned by `then 3`.

Comment: Your `then 1` is actually chained after `then 3`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with promises. The return value of `work` is the return value of the "then3" call.

Answer (score 1):

This is foremost a matter of syntax. What you are doing is equivalent to

```
const fn = () => {
    const promiseA = work();
    const promiseB = promiseA.then(finish); // then 1
    return promiseB;
};

const work = () => {
    const promiseC = Promise.resolve(1);
    const promiseD = promiseC.then(process1); // then 2
    const promiseE = promiseD.then(process2); // then 3
    return promiseE;
};
```

just introducing some extra variables (and also I've simplified the function expressions).

Now we can clearly see that the result of `work()` is what is returned by it, so `promiseA === promiseE`. So yes, `finish` is chained to the result of the "then3" call.

Knowing that `then` creates a new promise (for the eventual result of the callback) instead of returning the original one, we can also conclude that `promiseE !== promiseC`, so `finish` is *not* chained onto `Promise.resolve(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Each `then` will await its preceding promise and then run in turn.

If the preceding promise returns a value, the argument passed to the callback will be that value, or if it returns another promise, the argument to the callback will be the value returned from that promise.

[Section 2.2.6.1](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-37) of the promise plus specification states:

> If/when promise is fulfilled, all respective onFulfilled callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to then.

It is guaranteed that `finish(finalResult)` will run with the result of `process2(result)` (unless there's an error, of course.)

I found [this article](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) to be extremely enlightening on getting to grips with the guts of promises.